# Apache HttpAsyncClient thread count configuration

Tags: java, spring, apache, asynchttpclient

I'm trying to use AsyncRestTemplate with custom Apache HttpAsyncClient.

First i used simple new AsyncRestTemplate();
And when i added logs with thread name to future callback i saw that all of them was different (SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1..n).

Later i needed to implement custom ssl logic in my AsyncRestTemplate, so i added HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory to constructor.

Then i had some issues in my BL so i started to debug and saw that only two threads was used in future callback I/O dispatcher 1 and I/O dispatcher 2.

I tried to use this configuration but i still have only two threads.

```
return new AsyncRestTemplate(
       new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory(
               HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                    .setDefaultIOReactorConfig(IOReactorConfig.custom().setIoThreadCount(20).build())
                    .build()
       )
);
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: So you want to always have 20 threads open for your HttpAsyncClient? Am I understanding correctly? Is it possible that the configuration only sets a maximum amount and doesn't enforce any minimum?

Comment: @AustinSchäfer
I use retry mechanism with Thread.sleep() in callback, so all 2 threads almost all time in sleeping. 20 will be enough for my logic. Actually i don't need 20 all time opened, just have some kind of pool with 20 ready for working thread.
hopefully i clearly described the problem.